# No custom icon or sound in Ionic Native Push

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get this working https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

With FireBase Cloud Messaging

Here is the code

```
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions, AndroidPushOptions, IOSPushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';

pushsetup() {
    const options: PushOptions  = {

     android: {
         senderID: '**********',
         icon: "notification",
         iconColor: "blue",
         sound: true,
         vibrate: true,
         forceShow: true
     },

     ios: {
         alert: true,
         badge: true,
         sound: true
     },

  };

  const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

  pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
    if (notification.additionalData.foreground) {
      let youralert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'New Push notification',
        message: notification.message
      });
      youralert.present();
    }
  });

  pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
     //do whatever you want with the registration ID
  });

  pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => alert('Error with Push plugin' + error));
  }
```

How push looks now:

[image]

Unfortunately there is still no custom icon or sound or vibration :(

I copied the notification png, basically everywhere now in the android/res folder :)

Has anyone had any success with this? Do you actually have to use the AndroidPushOptions import anywhere?